# Написание Н и НН

Tags: орфография, причастия, нн

"Площадь оцеплена" — почему одна "н"?

Comment: Это действительно полная фраза?

Answer (score 6):

*Оцепле**нн**ый* — полное страдательное причастие.
*Оцепле**н**а* — краткое причастие глагола [**ОЦЕПИТЬ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C).

Краткие причастия пишутся с одной буквой **Н**. См., например, [**здесь**](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/prichastie/kratkoye.html).

[**Словоформы слова "оцеплен"**](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD).